# Equivalent of Ember.js yield in Sails.js w/Handlebars (SPA style)

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js, sails.js

So basically I want to do something that I can do in ember with handlebars but without using ember just sails.js and handlebars.

I set up sails project like so: `sails new fooProject --template=handlebars` after running `npm install sails-generate-views-handlebars`.

Great I have a layout file, all my files end in `.handlebars` woot.

But I would like to do something like this:

**Views:**

`views/index.handlebars`

```
{{>header}}
    {{yield}}
{{>footer}}
```

`/views/partials/foo.handlebars`

```
<div class="foo stuff">...</div>
```

**Router:**

`config/routes.js`

```
'/': {
    view: 'index',
    controller: 'FooController',
    action: 'index'
}
```

**Controller:**

`controllers/FooController`

```
index: function(req, res){
    return res.view({partials: 'partials/foo'}); // <-- I want foo partial in the yield.
}
```

So that I end up with this **output:**

```
<header>...</header>
    <div class="foo stuff">
<footer>...</footer>
```

Anytime my user navigates I'd like to render the new partial into that `{{yield}}` block without reloading the page. But that doesn't work, (I've tried). 
So how would I accomplish this?

To help clarify what I'm going for is a Single Page Application feel without having to use a front-end framework as well.

Comment: Unless things has been changed, sails renders template in the backend, so I believe there's no way to do this without a front-end framework easily.

Answer (score 2):

It can't be done without front end framework (or use basic XHR/ AJAX vanilla JS if you want to). Since Sails is server side engine and rendering views in server side, which means the page must be reload.

You can use any front end framework, and get any partial views from Sails's views as well if you want to hybrid front end (partial load) and back end (Sails) view engine.

Comment: So, I'm aware the sails renders on the backend, I guess I'm more looking for a way that I could respond with a partial to like a ajax call. So yea like a hybrid system. I want routing on the backend and I am doing some page loads but I want some single page *style* portions.

Comment: To achive "hybrid system" as I mentioned, just create a view like usual in Sails. BUT that view is not a whole HTML. Lemme give an example, assuming that you are using Asngular and Angular-ui-router:

Layout view: `<HTML><body><ui-view></body></HTML>` this should be your basic layout.
Body view: `<div>here is body</div>`

You can use both Sails rendering engine (EJS, Dust, etc.) and Angular rendering engine on both of that view. But remember to call just a body and put in on your main layout.